# Run code at specific time of day using Combine

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

My goal is to use Combine to run code at a specific time of day. In the code below, I use Combine to update a SwiftUI textview when a timer fires. I'd like the text view to be updated at a specific time of day rather than when the timer fires. I believe NotificationCenter can be used for the purpose, but I'm not quite sure how to make this work as documentation is lacking.

Can you solve this problem and use Notification Center to update the textview at a certain time of the day (for example, 6 pm)?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    @State private var counter = 0


    var body: some View {

        Text("The time is now \(counter)")
            .onReceive(timer) { time in
                if self.counter == 30 {
                    self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                }
                    self.counter += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if your app is not running or not in the foreground at that time of day?

Comment: I'd still like the code to be ran at that time of the day. The code needs to be ran at a specific time so I don't think that background fetch will work. I was hoping using combine with NotificationCenter could fix this problem, but I'm open to hearing anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do something even when your app is not foreground, you need to use [the UserNotifications framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications).

Read [“Scheduling a Notification Locally from Your App”](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app).

The basic summary is:

- Create a `UNMutableNotificationContent`.
- Create a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`.
- Create a `UNNotificationRequest` using the content and the trigger.
- Add the request to the `UNUserNotificationCenter`.

Comment: I've used the UserNotifications framework to send notifications to user, but when I've done this it's always displayed a notification to the user. I'd like to run the code without displaying a notification to the user. The article you linked says "Use local notifications to get the user's attention". How can code be ran this way without getting the users attention?

Comment: You could try using a push notification if you have a server. Otherwise, you’ll have to notify the user. This is iOS. You don’t get to just do things behind the user’s back.

Comment: Background fetch is a local IOS mechanism for running code without notifying the user. The problem is that this might not necessarily run at the specific requested time.